# What is the CSS to fill parent IFrame, or resize keeping aspect when full screen?

Tags: html, css, iframe, pixi.js

I'm porting a game I wrote to be a pixi.js HTML5 game that I can embed on itch.io. My game prints to a `canvas`, which is on a HTML file. itch.io embeds that HTML file in an `iframe`, and provides a full screen button that shows the `iframe` in full screen.

My game is running at a fixed resolution of 720x960 - before CSS scaling. `itch.io` has the `iframe` at a fixed size, that I can set using its interface. I have it set to 720x960 to match the game.

I am trying to write CSS for the HTML file that will resize the canvas as follows:

1. When displayed in the `iframe`, the `canvas` expands to fit the `iframe`, maintaining aspect ratio and centering if the aspect ratio of the `iframe` differs from the aspect ratio of the game.
2. When displayed in full screen, the `canvas` expands to fit the screen, maintaining aspect ration and centering on the screen.

I've tried two semi-successful approaches:

Firstly, I tried using the style `canvas { width 100%; height 100%}`. This fit the `iframe` perfectly,  but expanded the smaller dimension to the full width of the screen in full screen, meaning that the longer dimension was off the screen.

Secondly,  I tried using the following:

```
      canvas, html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      canvas {
        max-width: 100vw;
        max-height: 100vh;
        position: absolute;
      }

      @media (min-width: 75vh)
      {
        canvas {
          width: 75vh; /* (720 / 960) * 100*/
          height: 100vh;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translateX(-50%)
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 75vh)
      {
        canvas {
          width: 100vw;
          height: 133.333vw; /* (960 / 720) * 100 */
          display: flex;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%)
        }
      }
```

which worked perfectly on full screen, but moved the canvas partially off the `iframe` (as shown in the screenshot) - with my suspicion being that `vh` and `vw` are based on the window, not the `iframe`.
[image: Second approach with the canvas off the screen]

HTML that the browser gets (as the canvas is added by pixi.js) is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>webpack App</title>
        <style>
            <!-- CSS as above is here -->
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <canvas width="720" height="960" style="touch-action: none; cursor: inherit;"></canvas>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

What is the css to include in my html file to have it fit the iframe appropriately, but also expand appropriately when fullscreen?

Comment: Can you post the html also?

Comment: HTML has been added - following PIXI.js adding the canvas

Comment: any chance you can make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't know how in this case? I'm asking for what CSS, knowing that mine is likely completely wrong - but trying to provide the 'what have you tried' part. Not sure how to get the same result with less CSS.

Comment: can you try CSS as is used in following example : https://www.rossis.red/wasm.html#making_a_splash

Comment: @domis86 Not perfectly, but gave me basis for my response. Answering own question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved with the following CSS. The `max-height` and `max-width` need to be adjusted to be appropriate for the aspect ratio.

```
<style>
  html, body
  {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  body
  {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;  
  }
  canvas
  {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 133.333vw;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 75vh;
  }
  </style>
```