# Pixi.js Application will not completely fill the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixi.js

I am developing a game using pixi.js and have been unable to make the application fill the entire screen. I saw [this tutorial](https://codepen.io/aenima/pen/RjeddK) and added the resize method to my code, but when it is called it leaves a small five to ten pixel border around the application. I have also tried using position: absolute which then removes the border on the bottom and right sides, but not the top and left. I am unable to get it to resize to the top left of the screen for the life of me. My code is below:

I hope I inserted that correctly but as you can see after a name is typed in and play is pressed it does not fill the entire screen and leaves that gap in the top and left sides. Please let me know if you can help - thanks!

```js
//Instance Variables
var currentGame;

//Input Variables
var mouse = {};
var keyUp = false;
var keyDown = false;
var keyLeft = false;
var keyRight = false;

//Add button listener and key inputs when page loads
window.onload = function() {
  id("play-btn").addEventListener("click", play);
  setupInputs();
}

//Verify correct name and start
function play() {
  let name = id("name-input").value;
  if (name === "Enter name" || name === "") {
    error("Please enter a name.");
  } else if (name.length < 3) {
    error("Name must be at least 3 characters.");
  } else if (name.length > 20) {
    error("Name must be shorter than 21 characters.");
  } else {
    startGame(name);
  }
}

//Hide menu div, show game div, and create game object
function startGame(name) {
  hide(id("menu-div"));
  currentGame = new Game(name);
  id("game-div").appendChild(currentGame.app.view);
  resize(currentGame.app);
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    resize(currentGame.app);
  });
  show(id("game-div"));
}

function Game() {
  this.app = new PIXI.Application({
    autoResize: true,
    resolution: devicePixelRatio,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000
  });
}

function resize(app) {
  app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth + 30, window.innerHeight + 30);
}

function hide(element) {
  element.classList.add("hidden");
  for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
    hide(element.children[i]);
  }
}

function show(element) {
  element.classList.remove("hidden");
  for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
    show(element.children[i]);
  }
}

function error(message) {
  id("name-input").value = "Enter name";
  id("error-text").textContent = message;
  id("error-text").classList.remove("hidden");
}

//Setup player inputs
function setupInputs() {
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
  });
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.button === 0) {
      mouse.left = true;
    } else if (event.button === 2) {
      mouse.right = true;
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    if (event.button === 0) {
      mouse.left = false;
    } else if (event.button === 2) {
      mouse.right = false;
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {

    }
    if (event.key === "w" || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
      keyUp = true;
    }
    if (event.key === "a" || event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      keyLeft = true;
    }
    if (event.key === "s" || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
      keyDown = true;
    }
    if (event.key === "d" || event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      keyRight = true;
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "w" || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
      keyUp = false;
    }
    if (event.key === "a" || event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      keyLeft = false;
    }
    if (event.key === "s" || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
      keyDown = false;
    }
    if (event.key === "d" || event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      keyRight = false;
    }
  });
}


// Helper Functions
function id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function qs(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#menu-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

#menu-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}

#play-btn {
  font-size: 35pt;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#name-input {
  font-size: 35pt;
}

#error-text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#game-div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: none;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/v4.5.5/pixi.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="js/pixi.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu-div">
    <div id="menu-title">
      <img src="assets/title.png" alt="title">
    </div>
    <div id="menu-middle">
      <input id="name-input" value="Enter name">
      <button id="play-btn">Play!</button>
    </div>
    <p id="error-text" class="hidden"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="game-div" class="hidden">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try using css as is sugegsted in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295318/what-is-the-css-to-fill-parent-iframe-or-resize-keeping-aspect-when-full-screen?noredirect=1#comment110201044_62295318 - and also in answer below it.

Comment: That fixed the gap on the left side, now just the top... now I know what to research more though thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS's object-fit:

```css
canvas {
    object-fit: cover
}
```